# WinAPI DrawText new line

Tags: windows, winapi, drawtext

How do I make each string appear from new line?

```
int i = 1;
char *s = *environ;
    for (; s; i++) {
        DrawText(hdc, s, -1, &rect,
            DT_WORDBREAK | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_BOTTOM);
            s = *(environ + i);
         }
```

Comment: Uhm, by moving the destination rectangle down for each new line. And today is your lucky day, because someone even implemented an [OffsetRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162746.aspx) function for you!

Comment: If you read what IInspectable just said I assume the next question is "how do I get the height of the line I just drew". Well you have three options. The first two should give you the same result: `GetTextExtentPoint32()` and `DrawText(DT_CALCRECT)`. These will measure the bounding box of the string you are drawing, so if the ascent or descent of characters in one environment variable differs you'll get differing line height. The other way is to use `GetTextMetrics()` and `TEXTMETRIC.tmHeight`. This will give you the maximum possible line height for the currently selected font.

Comment: This latter one is probably the one to go for, as you get a consistent line height (and this line height is likely what `DrawText()` uses for multiline drawing anyway). You can also always just build a combined string of environment variables separated by newlines, but without knowing what your overall goal is I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: ...actually, does `DT_CALCRECT` work as I just specified or does it behave like `GetTextMetrics()` in the case of a single line? Someone who wants to go for it would have to check; I always just use `GetTextMetrics()` since for the moment I need to get the line height ahead of time in my programs. (That may change in the future.)

Comment: @andlabs A fourth option : *If the function succeeds, the return value is the height of the text in logical units*

Comment: Right; I think that would be the same as `GetTextExtentPoint32()`, but I wouldn't know for sure. Also I don't know what your compiler is but `environ` might not work correctly in the face of Unicode environment variable values... if it doesn't then you will need to use `GetEnvironmentStringsW()`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the value returned by the `DrawText` function (the height of the text drawn) to offset the rectangle for the next line of text.

```
int i = 1;
char *s = *environ;
for (; s; i++) {
    int height = DrawText(hdc, s, -1, &rect,
        DT_WORDBREAK | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_BOTTOM);
    OffsetRect(&rect, 0, height);
    s = *(environ + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new line character `'\n'` to the end of each string.

Correction: I thought that all strings will be drawn at once...

Comment: You should probably delete this answer.